# .tflite vs .lite file formats. Which to use? Why?

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow, file-format, file-type

1. What is the difference between .tflite and .lite file?
2. Which file format is recommended, and why? Is any of them is deprecated?
3. What is the correct way to train image categorisation model to .tflite model?

I have downloaded TensorFlow's sample project and it works on .tflite format. But my image categorisation model is of .lite format. I changed my model's format to .tflite and my project run successfully without crashing, but it does not gave any result/output. Not sure if its the model, or the code that is causing the issue.

```
private let modelDataHandler: ModelDataHandler? = ModelDataHandler(modelFileName: "graph", labelsFileName: "labels", labelsFileExtension: "txt")
```

Comment: `.tflite` and  `.lite` file formats no difference. I recommended you to use `.tflite` formats (TensorFlow formats). unfortunately, ML Kit Console at this moment only takes files with `.tflite`extension.

Comment: Okay, I have read the same statement in some other answers on stackoverflow too.. 
But I need some clarification on training the model. Can a model be trained in multiple ways? Can its output vary as per export method used? Actually I have two models, 1 from TensorFlow, and other trained by me, But the sample app provided by TensorFlow gives output with the same model only, not with my model....